# How to open csv with blank columns correctly in open office

Tags: csv, openoffice

I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
"column1",,"column3"
"column1",column2,
```

Sometimes the CSV contains blank column(s). Is it possible to open it correctly in Open Office?

Comment: As Mike's answer indicates, this should work.  To determine why it's not in your case, you will need to provide specifics on exactly how you're doing it.

Answer (score 2):

It works perfectly well for me in Apache OpenOffice Calc v. 4.1.4, as well as in LibreOffice Calc v. 5.0.4.2 and Microsoft Office Excel 2007. You will face a popup window once you try to open the CSV file and you have to ensure that in your case you have "comma" selected as the separator.

**Apache OpenOffice Calc v. 4.1.4:**

[image]
[image]

**LibreOffice Calc v. 5.0.4.2:**

[image]
[image]